# EJB ,Rest, JPA NullPointerException

Tags: java, rest, jpa, ejb

i use "jpa"  and  "ejb "and "resf "in this example:

**controller.service:**

```
    package controller;

import model.bl.RegisterManImpl;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;

@Path("/X")
@SessionScoped
public class Service {


    @EJB
    private RegisterManImpl register;

    @GET
    @Path("/Y")
    public String ok() { 
            register.register();


            return "hello";
    }

}
```

**persistence.xml:**

```
    <persistence version="1.0"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="DB_CONNECTION">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>JTA-Connection</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>None-JTA-Connection</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**model.bl.RegisterManImpl:**

```
    package model.bl;


import model.entity.Customer;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Stateful
public class RegisterManImpl {
    @PersistenceContext (name = "DB_CONNECTION")
    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public void register()
    {
        Customer c2 = new Customer();
        c2.setName("sa333");
        c2.setFamily("t222");
        entityManager.persist(c2);
    }

}
```

**model.to.Customer:**

```
    package model.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity(name = "Customer")

public class Customer {
    @Basic
    @Column (name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name" ,length = 5)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "family")
    public String getFamily() {
        return family;
    }

    public void setFamily(String family) {
        this.family = family;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    //@Id
    //@GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name, family;
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>JavaServerFaces</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>controller</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/sami/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**index.jsp:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="/sami/X/Y">
    <button>register</button>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

***When I run this simple example,I see this error:***

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controller.Service.ok(Service.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:165)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:276)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1171)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1103)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1053)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1043)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:406)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:477)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:662)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**please help me.**

***thanks for your attention .***

Answer (score 0):

Customer model class is not mapped in Persistence file so the entityManager.persist(c2) fail.

Comment: when i run this example with JSF(without REST and servlet),running well !!